# How to merge several rows that share the same foreign key, into columns?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a main table that stores information about the general details of a sample. There are also several rows in another table that have the main tables id as a foreign key. I want to merge the id's of these individual rows and the main table id into columns on a single row.

I've tried writing a view that creates rows joining data between sample_admittance. The problem is that it would create several rows to fit a unit id in only one column for each join.

```sql
 SELECT
    mt.project,
    mt.project_name,
    mt.client,
    mt.date,
    mt.location,
    u.unit,
    u.status
   FROM main_table mt
     JOIN units u ON u.main_table_id::text = mt.id::text;
```

I wanted it organized like:

```
main_table_id | unit_1 | unit_2 | unit_3 | ... | unit_10
```

but instead get multiple rows

```
main_table_id | unit

id_1          | un1
id_1          | un3
id_2          | un1
```

Comment: Will you only have 10 units?

Comment: Yes, 10 units will be the maximum, though there can be some rows with less than 10 related units.